# Different behaviour of background and src attribute of image view

Tags: android, material-design

I have this weird problem happening in my app. I have image view with    `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` and want it to come behind status bar.

When I use `android: background`, it works properly as expected as shown below. [notice blue background in status bar]

[image]

But when I use src attribute, it does not go behind the status bar.

[image]

Am I missing something? Help is appreciated.

Here is my activity XML.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/full_background"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:contentDescription="full_background"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_activity_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: tried, same issue

Comment: in your theme window translucentstatus is true or false??

Comment: It is true, but tried with or without it, same issue persists

Comment: I am feeling you are using your imageview not at proper place in xml

Comment: @HiteshMatnani No, Image view is in proper place, solution given by Dheeraj works but my my toolbar goes under status bar now, any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

**Try using:** `FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS` IT allow window to extend outside of the screen

```
 Window window = getWindow();
 window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

Comment: Okay, this worked but it took my toolbar under status bar. :(

Comment: okk,i think i got it,just remove all  android:fitsSystemWindows="true" except from the imageview

Comment: Nope, didn't work, I will have to research more on this issue